# header-args in org-mode Properties

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

Trying to figure out how to use header-args, but doesn't work for me. I specify:

```
****** org-heading header
:PROPERTIES:
:header-args+:shell: :var foo=hukarz
:END:
```

, but there's no output with this:

```
#+NAME: get-openstack-token
#+BEGIN_SRC shell :results verbatim
echo $foo
#+END_SRC
```

Comment: I think you misplaced the `+`. Put it behind `shell`, as in `:header-args:shell+:`. (This is untested.)

Comment: What @Tobias said, plus you need to quote the value `:var foo = "hukarz"`.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me

```
:PROPERTIES:
:header-args: :var foo="hukarz"
:END:

#+BEGIN_SRC shell 
echo ${foo}
#+END_SRC


#+RESULTS:
: hukarz


** subsection 2
  :PROPERTIES:
  :header-args: :var foo="bar2"
  :END:
  #+BEGIN_SRC shell
  echo ${foo}
  #+END_SRC

  #+RESULTS:
  : bar2
```